# Rails: 'has_many :stickies' the "Rails Way"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app with `Users`: Users `has_many :posts`

I have a `sticky` boolean in my `Posts` table.

I need `stickies` to be user specific (because I will have other users' posts show on each others pages) & so I have 'has_many :stickies' in my Posts class.

My question is, should I remove the `sticky` column & add a 'Stickies' table or is there a way to make the stickies user specific with the boolean? If so, how & would it be better?

Thank you in advance.

---

```
def self.visible_to(user)
   where('posts.user_id = :user_id or favorites.user_id = :user_id', { :user_id => user.id }).includes(:favorites).order('sticky, favorites.created_at, posts.created_at)
end
```

---

So, having 'has_many :stickies' is better than using a boolean in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do in `post.rb:`

```
scope :stickies, where(sticky: true)
```

now you can call:

```
user.posts.stickies
```

Comment: can't see your edit yet, but, what you mean by `to make the stickies user specific`?

Comment: Please check again. What I mean by "user specific" is that when user a favorites user b's post, that post will show up on user a's page. Now if user b's post is a sticky, then that mean it would show up on user a's page as a sticky

Comment: how you as a user add a post to favorites? what relations do you use for this?

Comment: Post: belongs_to :user, has_many :favorites -- User: has_many :posts, has_many :favorites -- Favorites: belongs_to :user, belongs_to :post

Comment: I assume in favorites you have only post_id and user_id right?

Comment: you should build a relation between user and posts through favorites too, so you can call user.favorited_posts that will return you an array of posts, and then call .stickies on this array to get the sticky ones.. I wanted to start a chat with you to solve this but you have a small rating and it wont't let you in chat. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association.

Comment: I didnt want the favorited_posts that are, but rather exclude that favorite posts that are sticky from being a sticky.. That way, I can favorite a post from another user who stickied it & it will show up on my page regularly & not as a sticky

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33742/discussion-between-rmagnum2002-and-jon)

Comment: get back to chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33742/discussion-between-rmagnum2002-and-jon